# Uploading file with PUT method in PHP

Tags: php, parameters, upload, yii2, put

For my RESTFUL API server I'm trying to use the "PUT" method for uploading a file.

Actions started as reading php://input.

So, how can pass file name or some other parameters to action and display them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **post** method therefore, you can collect data from form-data using $**_POST** the super global variable because, there is no super global like $**_PUT** for put method.